# Is there any English translation of either of these Weierstrass publications?

Tags: translation-request

1. Karl Weierstrass, "Über continuirliche Functionen eines reellen Arguments, die für keinen Werth des letzeren einen bestimmten Differentialquotienten besitzen," (On continuous functions of a real argument which possess a definite derivative for no value of the argument)
2. Karl Weierstrass, Abhandlungen aus der Functionenlehre [Treatises from the Theory of Functions]